# How can I stop an ongoing sync process on my Desire?

Tags: htc-desire, processes

yesterday I decided to upload all my phone's photos using PICASA. I thought the task would have required one hour or so but instead it is still running and is extremely slow! I would like to stop it but it seems impossible, I have the 'notification' of the ongoing process and whatever thing I do (reboot phone, shut down, advanced task killer, android assistant) as soon as I start an internet connection the process appear. Please help me close it!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried but they didn't seem to make the icon disappear. After wandering through settings and application as suggested by Matthew this is what I finally did and it seems to work: Settings --> Application --> Manage App --> Running --> myuploads --> Force Stop and eventually the icon of ongoing process was gone! Thank you for the important clue!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go to `Settings -> Accounts and sync` and if you have an entry for Picasa, shut off sync for it.  If that doesn't work disable **Background data** in the same place, then go to your Media app or wherever you set up the sync and shut it off.  If you can't then you should go to `Settings -> Applications -> All` and clear the data for the relevant app(s).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Setting and from there click on the application manager
2. Once you are on application manager, swipe across the categories to find All. This will give you a list of all applications on your phone. Your application manager has three categories - a) Downloaded b) Running and c) All.
3. Once you select All, scroll down the list of applications to find Download Manager.
4. On Download Manager, click on the button that says Clear Data. Once the data is cleared, the download notification on the notification window will go away.